# Springboot application (with Kafka) stops working if it does not get continuous messages to consume

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Java spring boot application that consumes batches of Kafka messages. The batches of messages arrive at irregular intervals. If there is a few hours gap between receiving the message, the app stops working and messages stop getting consumed.
If we manually restart the app, it starts consuming the messages again.
How to fix this issue? What could be the root cause behind this behaviour?

Comment: i) what is the time duration the application remains up?
ii) what does the application console says when it stops?

Comment: Most of the time, such situations are caused by the listener thread being "stuck" in user code; take a thread dump the next time it happens. DEBUG logging will help too.

Comment: Agree with above. Restarting the app is causing a consumer group rebalance and will restart the consumer thread heartbeats. Without gathering logs, it's hard to know what the root cause is

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.